# has_and_belongs_to_many generates NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm facing the above issue when testing the association between the two tables in my console.

This is how my models look like:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :plan
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
end
```

And here is the migration I generated to join reference the above table:

```
class CreateTeamsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   create_table :teams_users, :id => false do |t|

     t.integer :team_id
     t.integer :user_id
   end

   add_index :teams_users, :team_id
   add_index :teams_users, :user_id    
 end
end
```

When I try to push in the console a user to a team or vice versa, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Any idea of what can be generating such an issue?

Thanks!

UPDATE

Here's my schema.rb

```
# encoding: UTF-8
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160207132759) do

  create_table "roles", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "teams", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "value"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "teams_users", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "team_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  add_index "teams_users", ["team_id"], name: "index_teams_users_on_team_id"
  add_index "teams_users", ["user_id"], name: "index_teams_users_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "role_id"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

And here is the code I run in the console:

```
u = User.new
u.email = "test@test.com"
u.password = "123456789"
u.save
t = Team.new
t.name = "test teat"
t.save

u.teams << t
```

As requested; here's the error itself. I also spotted that I get the same error when trying to destroy_all the users.

It looks like the error is in the "join table"

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:79:in `cached_counter_attribute_name'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:75:in `has_cached_counter?'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:83:in `update_counter'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:65:in `insert_record'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:522:in `block (2 levels) in concat_records'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:389:in `add_to_target'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:521:in `block in concat_records'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:519:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:519:in `concat_records'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:42:in `concat_records'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:153:in `block in concat'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:168:in `block in transaction'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `block in transaction'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:219:in `within_new_transaction'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
... 6 levels...
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/criteofootball/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

Comment: "When I try to push in the console a user to a team or vice versa" with what code?

Comment: After creating a user and saving it in the variable u and a team in a variable t, I run the following:

u.teams << t

Comment: Please post you db schema and the exact code your running that causes the error

Comment: @milesStanfield - done (y)

Comment: can you post the full contents of the error your receive as well?

Comment: do you get any errors when you run this code in your console ```Team.create!(name: 'test')```

Comment: @MilesStanfield I don't get any error; the entry is correctly added to the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in ActiveRecord 4.1.0 when used with Ruby 2.2.0. You can see an example of it affecting another project [here](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/issues/380). The fix is in ActiveRecord 4.1.2 so upgrading should resolve this for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mikej! I updated rails to the 4.1.2 version and the association is now working.